# Find all whole number solutions of the following equation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

While training for a math olympiad(university level) I stumbled upon the following problem. Find all $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$${ n \choose 0 } + {n \choose 1}+{n \choose 2} + {n \choose 3} = 2^k.$$
Now I have thought about two ways of solving this. The first is by expanding the left hand side to get a polynomial in $n$, and by this finding restrictions on $n$ and $k$. The other way would be by repeatedly using Pascal's formula and the fact that 
$$2^j = \sum_{i=0}^j {j \choose i}$$
for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Both have not given me any success. Am I on a right track? Could you give me some hints, or an attempt at a solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing I notice is that each of $n=0,1,2,3$ immediately give solutions as per the binomial theorem. Beyond that...?

Comment: Yes, I hoped that would be the only solutions, but alas, $n=7$, $k=6$ suffice. There are also some more solutions that are bigger. They seem to be pretty random, bur $n$ seems to be prime every time, except when $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Comment: And cool because of what you said about the binomial theorem, I now know $2$ ways of understanding that fact about the $j$-th power of $2$ :)

Comment: Using Mathematica, the only larger solution (for $n$ up to 1000) I've found so far is with $n=23$. But that's a very brute force search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $n>3$.

Expanding the LHS and simplifying gives
$$\frac{1}{6}(n+1)(n^2-n+6) = 2^k.$$
So except for one factor of $3$, both $n+1$ and $n^2+n-6$ are powers of $2$. If the factor of $3$ is in $n+1$, then $n = 3\cdot 2^r-1$ with $r\ge 1$, so that
$$n^2+n-6 = (3\cdot 2^r-1)^2 - (3\cdot 2^r-1) + 6
     = 8 - 3\cdot 2^4 + 9\cdot 2^{2r} - 3\cdot 2^{r+1}
     = 8(1 - 2^{r-3} - 2^r + 2^{2r} + 2^{2r-3}).$$
In order for this to be a power of $2$, we must have $r=3$; otherwise the second factor is odd. $r=3$ gives $n = 3\cdot 2^3-1 = 23$.

Alternatively, the factor of $3$ is in $n^2-n+6$, so that $n+1 = 2^r$ is a power of $2$ with $r\ge 1$. But then
\begin{align*}
  n^2-n+6 &= (2^r-1)^2 - (2^r-1) + 6 = 2^{2r} - 3\cdot 2^r + 8 \\
    &= 9 -3\cdot 2^r + (2^{2r}-1) \\
    &= 9 - 3\cdot 2^r + 3(2^{2r-2}+2^{2r-4} + \ldots + 2^2 + 1) \\
    &= 12 - 3\cdot 2^r + 3(2^{2r-2}+2^{2r-4}+\ldots + 2^2) \\
    &= 3(4-2^r + 2^{2r-2}+2^{2r-4} + \ldots + 2^2) \\
    &= 24(1-2^{r-3}+2^{2r-5}+2^{2r-7}+\ldots+ 2),
\end{align*}
and in order for this to be $3$ times a power of $2$, we must again have $r=3$, so that $n = 2^3-1=7$.

Comment: "in order for this to be a power of 2, we must have r=3" Could you explain this more? Because r=0 gives 8=2^3

Comment: The case $r=0$ doesn't need consideration, because it implies $n=2$, and we are already assuming that $n>3$.